# Confusion in this line integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given vector field (M,N,P) with components as M=3y^2  + 2z^2 , N= (6x - 10z)y , P=4xz -5y^2

along portion from (1,0,1) to (3,4,5) of Cis intersection of two surfaces z^=x^2 + y^2 (cone)
and z=y+! .Assume usual positive orientation .

Now if i apply stokes theorem then curlF =0 here . so line integral should be zero .But it is not . Why this inconsistency

Comment: It's a bit unclear what the contour is. The "along portion from $(1,0,1)$ to $(3,4,5)$" makes me suspect it's not a closed contour. If it isn't, the integral has no reason to be $0$. Anyway, a potential of the field makes the evaluation of line integrals easy.

Comment: Do I interpret it right, that we have a curve $C$ which is the intersection of the two surfaces $\operatorname{cone} = \{(x,y,z) : z^2 = x^2 + y^2\}$ and $\operatorname{plane} = \{(x,y,z) : z = y+1\}$, and you shall integrate the field along the arc of $C$ connecting the two points $(1,0,1)$ and $(3,4,5)$ that has positive orientation [which is a little cumbersome to properly define, but here is the arc with $y \geqslant 0$ for all points on the arc]?

Comment: @DanielFischer yes . i think cone plane cuts cone into arc which is type of ellipse .but i see a trick here . if a vector field is conservative which is here then we need not go to do all trouble just find potential function n then subtract points n we r done . i think the other things in the question is just to confuse what do you say

Comment: Right, you don't need a parametrisation, just start point and end point. "Anyway, a potential of the field makes the evaluation of line integrals easy."

Comment: @DanielFischerhttp://math.stackexchange.com/questions/979775/is-my-solution-to-this-surface-integral-problem-correct